# Res folder location in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to add app icons to my Cordova app (android currently):

```
<platform name="android">    
    <icon src="res/icons/mipmap-ldpi/ic_launcher.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/mipmap-xdpi/ic_launcher.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/mipmap-xxdpi/ic_launcher.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/mipmap-xxxdpi/ic_launcher.png" density="xxhdpi" />
</platform>
```

I get the error:
Source path does not exist: res/icons/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png

I have tried multiple different paths in `config.xml` and tried multiple places where to actually put the images, but I haven't seen clearly in any documentation or stackoverflow questions where to actually put the icon files. They seem to need to be in a folder called `res` but I can't figure out where to put that folder in Cordova.

Edit:
I have tried to put the files in:

- www/
- www/res/
- platforms/android/
- platforms/android/res/
- platforms/android/platform_www/
- platforms/android/platform_www/res/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the same level as www

```
/www
/res
/platforms/android
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: Ahhhhh it was a typo - yep that location worked thank you very much